# Centering buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to center these buttons, but most stuff online does not work. `<center>` does not work and `text-align:center` does not work.

The buttons should show up in the exact same way, except centered in the middle. If you try this, it will not work. there must be a problem, I guess.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>website</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.button0 {
position:fixed;
left:88px;
top:58px;
font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
font-size:8px;
font-weight:NORMAL;
}
.button1 {
position:fixed;
left:6px;
top:191px;
font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
font-size:8px;
font-weight:NORMAL;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.button2 {
position:fixed;
left:358px;
top:216px;
font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
font-size:8px;
font-weight:NORMAL;
}
</style>
<body>
<center>
<div class="button0"><input type="button" style="width: 268px;height: 145px;" value="Button"/></div>
<div class="button1"><input type="button" style="width: 40px;height: 88px;" value="Button"/></div>
<div class="button2"><input type="button" style="width: 76px;height: 73px;" value="Button"/></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to center - the text inside the buttons? Buttons themselves vertically?

Comment: Just FYI, you're missing a closing head tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.container {
text-align: center;
}

.center-element {
width: 100px;
text-align: left;
}
```

or

```
.container {
width: 200px;
}

.center-element {
width: 100px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

or

```
.container {
width: 200px;
}

.center-element {
width: 100px;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: hmm, i dont know why, but its not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign `position:fixed` and `top` & `left` and expect your elements to be centered. Typically, `margin: 0px auto` will work well. See example below.

```
.button0 {
    font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:NORMAL;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.button1 {
    font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:NORMAL;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.button2 {
    font-family:MS Shell Dlg 2;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:NORMAL;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/VhtWj/).

Comment: cool, it centers them but theyre positions dont use the ones given

Comment: So you want to center them by some other manner other than FIFO?

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap it in a `relative` div.  Then you can set the margins of the left and right to `auto`.

Just to be clear, is this what you're looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>website</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
    <div style="position:relative; width:500px; height:200px; background:green; text-align:center">
        <input type="button" style="width: 268px;height: 145px;" value="Button1"/>
        <input type="button" style="width: 40px;height: 88px;" value="Button2"/>
        <input type="button" style="width: 76px;height: 73px;" value="Button3"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think i tried that and the buttons werent in the place they should have been

Comment: You may need to wrap the buttons in another div if you want them to be together.  Then the buttons would not need the margin auto, but the wrapping div would.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYPSE/) - just turn the button to a block element, specify the width, and then auto margins left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Try vertically-centered text in a div.  See [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8QMGf/) for example.